# TF2 Static Transform publisher for rotated Lidar

Tags: ros, transform, 2dlidar, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI All,

I am a bit new to this. I have a robot with the scanner (RPLIDAR) located at the center of the the robot base, but it is rotated 90 degrees about axis z . What should I set the qw value for my static transform, its it needed? In the example I saw it set to 1 ? I tried below but it does not reflect the proper 90 degree rotation in rviz.

*node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 1.571 1 base_robot base_laser"*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397048/tf2-static-transform-publisher-for-rotated-lidar/) by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 34 on 2022-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't have to use quaternion notation for a static_transform_publisher, because it accepts yaw-pitch-roll in radians.

**Beware!** Euler angles are usually r-p-y in ros, but for this particular node the developers did it y-p-r.

So if you are looking down at the robot from above, and if your lidar is rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise from the robot's x-axis, then the y-p-r angles (in radians) are:

1.571 0 0

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on 2022-03-03**:
@ Mike Thank you will try that. I was reading the TF example and saw they had quanternion notation. I will try it using y-p-r and report back here. Thanks again.

**Comment by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on 2022-03-25**:
@ Mike thank you this worked.